# using windows username password in C#

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, credentials

how i can use windows stored username and password in my C# APP. I am looking for method which returns bool state of successful login. means :

```
bool isCredentialValid = CheckLogin(username, password);
```

so according to bool value I can show proper message.

**Updated**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter username : ");
        string user = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter password : ");
        string pass = Console.ReadLine();

        bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(user, pass);

        Console.WriteLine("State : {0}",isValid);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

this code is not working. when i enable **Guest account** it shows true for every login and when i disable **Guest account** it does not verifies even existing account. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: u mean with windows login and password

Comment: Are you sure the account you are using to test this is a machine account? If I try the code you provide it validates successfully. When I try to login with a disabled account an exception is thrown.

Comment: @ i am using the same username and password which i use to login, its working in windows 7 pc but not in XP

Comment: I am running on Windows XP SP3 and it is working ok. At first I tried it at my dev PC (using VS2008 on XPSP3) which was fine. Now I've also built a Release version and ran that on another XPSP3 machine which also ran ok. I ran the exe both as an Administrator and a normal user, in both cases it worked just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889.aspx) method. For example,

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
bool isCredentialValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
```

for local accounts, use ContextType.Machine.

Yet another way would be using win32 api [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

Answer (score 3):

Add  `using System.Security.Principal;`

```
//for current Username full
 string str = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Then u can use this username for authentication. 
For password it is different.